# Hibernate. Collection fields referenced SINGLE_TABLE inherited classes ignores DiscriminatorValue while fething

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Problem: one-to-many collection field ignores discriminator column and fetches all entries instead of dedicated subclass.

I am having base super-class with inheritance strategy SINGLE_TABLE.

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "state")
@Data
@Table(name = "named_entity", indexes = @Index(columnList = "state"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Entity
public class BaseNamedEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EntityState state; // declared for jpql purposes
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "collection_holder_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CollectionHolderEntity otmCollection; // field will be important later
}
```

And two sub-classes for states 'active' and 'deleted':

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("active")
public class ActiveNamedEntity extends BaseNamedEntity {
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("deleted")
public class DeletedNamedEntity extends BaseNamedEntity {
}
```

Base functionality (like spring data crud repository) works as expected:

```
((CrudRepository<ActiveNamedEntity, UUID>) activeDao).existsById(UUID.randomUUID());
// -> Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from named_entity activename0_ where activename0_.state='active' and activename0_.id=?
// Discriminator column is checked as expected
```

I tried to introduce entity that holds one-to-many relationship to one of the sub-classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collection_holder")
@Data
public class CollectionHolderEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "otmCollection", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) // Eager to avoid transactions in tests
    private List<ActiveNamedEntity> oneToManyCollection = new ArrayList<>(); // ActiveNamedEntity is subclass with corelated state = "active"
}
```

And it is seems like generated statements ignores discriminator columns once it tries to fetch collection field:
[image: unexpected state for this sub-class]

```
collectionHolderDao.findById(collectionHolderEntity.getId()) // reloading entity
                .orElseGet(() -> Assertions.fail("Expected to find holder " + collectionHolderEntity));
// -> Hibernate: select collection0_.id as id1_0_0_, onetomanyc1_.collection_holder_id as collecti4_1_1_, onetomanyc1_.id as id2_1_1_, onetomanyc1_.id as id2_1_2_, onetomanyc1_.name as name3_1_2_, onetomanyc1_.collection_holder_id as collecti4_1_2_, onetomanyc1_.state as state1_1_2_ from collection_holder collection0_ left outer join named_entity onetomanyc1_ on collection0_.id=onetomanyc1_.collection_holder_id where collection0_.id=?
// join contains only id reference, but not state check:
// left outer join named_entity onetomanyc1_ on collection0_.id=onetomanyc1_.collection_holder_id
```

Where **expected behavior** would be request, that contains state check for join: `left outer join named_entity onetomanyc1_ on collection0_.id=onetomanyc1_.collection_holder_id and onetomanyc1_.state="active"`

Am I missing some part of specification?

Maybe I should specify somewhere explicitly that it should introduce discriminator column to generated request. If so - what expected to do with many-to-many relationships?

So far I tried:

1. to move field that owns a relationship to sub-class (`ActiveNamedEntity` in this example) but doesn't seems like anything changes.
2. Switching fetch type with also gets same results

In this example I used `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.4.6`
with correlates to `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.31.Final`

Answer (score 0):

I still **don't think it is a expected behavior** but here is few things to get it out of the box:

1. Adding `@org.hibernate.annotations.Where(clause)` to each sub-class with correlated query:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("active")
@Where(clause = "state='active'")
public class ActiveNamedEntity extends BaseNamedEntity { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("deleted")
@Where(clause = "state='deleted'")
public class DeletedNamedEntity extends BaseNamedEntity { }
```

Or to collection attribute directly:

```
/*...*/
    @Where(clause = "state='active'")
    private List<ActiveNamedEntity> oneToManyCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

First one is seems more preferable since will be work universally.

2. Adding `@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter` (and corresponding filterDef) and enable it for each session. More of that in [this discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21061).
   I didn't have any luck with this method but theoretically it should work.

Comment: I didn't close question for now since it is seems like should work out of the box and I  am just missing some mappings in original question example.